# Where to find application after flatpak installation (gimp)

Tags: 16.04, gimp, flatpak

I have [installed](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/) `flatpak` to install `gimp` on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref
```

After the installation was done I couldn't find any application on my system, it also did not appear on my Desktop. Where to look for it?

**UPDATE:**
Searching for `gimp` did not give me the right result, anyway by searching for `GNU Image Manipulation Program` gave me the right result

Answer (score 24):

**In short:** Reboot or log out and log in after installing the `flatpak` package to see flatpak apps in the launcher.

Explanation:

Flatpak collects all `.desktop` files of system-wide installed applications in
`/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications` and of per-user applications in `~/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications`.<sup>[[1]](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1286#issuecomment-354554684)</sup>

Application launchers search for apps in `$XDG_DATA_HOME` directory (default `~/.local/share`) and `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` colon-separated list (default `/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/`).<sup>[[2]](https://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/ar01s02.html)[[3]](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)</sup>

`flatpak` Ubuntu package installs `/etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh` script that adds the aforementioned flatpak [export](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/basic-concepts.html#sandboxes) directories to `XDG_DATA_DIRS` *on startup*. And just running the script after install won't help, it has to be done before the desktop starts because it reads that environment variable only when starting.

Answer (score 17):

To run Gimp:

```
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP "$@"
```

But AFAIK there is a desktop file somewhere, I have a `~/.local/share/applications/org.gimp.GIMP.desktop` with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Graphics;2DGraphics;RasterGraphics;GTK;
Comment=Create images and edit photographs
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=gimp-2.10 --file-forwarding org.gimp.GIMP @@u %U @@
GenericName=Image Editor
Icon=org.gimp.GIMP
Keywords=GIMP;graphic;design;illustration;painting;
MimeType=image/bmp;image/g3fax;image/gif;image/x-fits;image/x-pcx;image/x-portable-anymap;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/x-portable-graymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/x-psd;image/x-sgi;image/x-tga;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-xwindowdump;image/x-xcf;image/x-compressed-xcf;image/x-gimp-gbr;image/x-gimp-pat;image/x-gimp-gih;image/tiff;image/jpeg;image/x-psp;application/postscript;image/png;image/x-icon;image/x-xpixmap;image/x-exr;image/x-webp;image/heif;image/heic;image/svg+xml;application/pdf;image/x-wmf;image/jp2;image/x-xcursor;
Name=Gimp 2.10
NoDisplay=false
Path[$e]=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=0
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
Version=1.0
X-Flatpak=org.gimp.GIMP
X-Flatpak-Tags=stable;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=General
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-OtherBinaries=gimp-2.10
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=GIMP
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.10.2
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

The real installation is in `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.gimp.GIMP/`

If you are used to "native" Gimp, be aware of some restrictions:

- the "recent files" are not shared with other apps in the system
- the /tmp directory as seen by Gimp is remapped to a directory specific to flatpak, so you cannot share files through that (which is unfortunately required for some apps, such as web browsers)
- the Python runtime is specific to Gimp
- the Gimp profile is buried in `~/.var/app/org.gimp.GIMP/config/GIMP/2.10/`
- you may want to use `Edit>Preferences>Folders` to setup folders in more "visible" directories for your brushes, patterns, scripts and plugins
- compatibility with the popular plugins (GMIC, resynthesize...) isn't clear. It seems this requires flatpak versions.

Answer (score 1):

To make Flatpak applications available in CLI, you can use a simple script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Put file in /usr/local/libexec/flatpak-runner and then
# symlink for instance /usr/local/bin/spotify and /usr/local/bin/gimp
# to ../libexec/flatpak-runner

declare -A pkgs

pkgs=(
 [spotify]=com.spotify.Client
 [gimp]=org.gimp.GIMP
)

cmd=`basename $0`
args=$@


flatpak run --command="$cmd" ${pkgs[$cmd]} $args
```