# How to make Thunderbird use a Flatpak app as default file handler?

Tags: flatpak

I'm trying to make Flatpak Libreoffice the default app for opening files in Thunderbird.

At the moment, Thunderbird (also a flatpak) is using System Handler as default. I tried changing it but cannot find where the libreoffice executable is on my system.

I found the libreoffice .desktop files in `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications` but Thunderbird doesn't seem to recognise the app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to find application after flatpak installation (gimp)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051438/where-to-find-application-after-flatpak-installation-gimp)

Comment: How to change the program which opens attachments in Thunderbird is explained [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1200880) That combined with https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051438/where-to-find-application-after-flatpak-installation-gimp should be sufficient to get you where you are trying to go.

Comment: I knew about the Thunderbird attachment settings, but when you choose "other" it makes you choose an executable file whereas flatpaks are run with a `flatpak run app` which cannot be chosen through the Thunderbird settings. I guess one possible solution would be to write a bash script to run the flatpak command. However since there is a .desktop file that runs the programme why isn't Thunderbird offering that as an option of apps like the Desktop Evironment? I tried pointing TB to the LO .desktop file to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. I had the same problem.  I want to use Microsoft Edge to open links in Thunderbird.

In thunderbird 102.10.0(64 bit) I went to Edit -> Settings and scrolled down to Files & Attachments.

For Content Type https  I selected action Use Other and then selected
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/com.microsoft.Edge

and now Microsoft Edge is invoked when I click on a link in Thunderbird.